# Where is the VB.Net debugger "Make Object ID" function?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

When using the visual studio 2008 debugger with c# i can right-click on a variable and choose "Make Object ID" which allows me to watch that object (via it's ID) regardless of whether it is in the current stack frame or not.

When the debugger is in VB code, (doesnt matter if it's run from a c# unit test or a vb unit test) That option isn't there.

Where did VB put this feature? Or does it simply not support it like so many other helpful c# features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know this feature is specialy designed for C# and J#. So it is not available when debugging VB.Net Code.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I afraid of, but was hoping somebody would prove otherwise.